# Python - Spotify API returning Error 400 "Malformed JSON"

Tags: python, json, http, python-requests, spotify

Heyo. I'm trying to make a small application in my spare time that uses the Spotify API . I have managed to get my program to use oAuth 2 to let a user authorize my app to manipulate their Spotify, but I have run into a problem with a certain endpoint on the Spotify API.

The endpoint I am having trouble with is https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/player/play (here's a link to their docs for the endpoint https://developer.spotify.com/console/put-play/). Whenever I try to make a put request to the endpoint I receive a 400 status code with the message "Malformed json" I get this message even when I copy/paste their own json from the docs, so I don't think it's a problem with how I am formatting my json, besides I have used json before to call other endpoints and they haven't had a problem with my formatting on those calls.

Here is my code:

```py
headers = {"Authorization":"Bearer {}".format(access_token)}

url = 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/player/play'
payload = {"context_uri": "spotify:album:5ht7ItJgpBH7W6vJ5BqpPr"}
r = requests.put(url, headers=headers, data=payload)
print(r)
print(r.text)
```

To clarify, `access_token` is the access token that I have gotten from their authorization process, and I am using python-requests to make the http requests (Here is the docs for that: https://requests.kennethreitz.org/en/master/)

I am wondering if the problem is due to the fact that Spotify uses colons int their track IDs and colons are also used in JSON? I saw in another thread on here that I should try to add `"Content-Type":"application/json"` to my headers but that didn't change the outcome at all.

Any help is greatly appreciated, and if you need any more info please let me know. Thank you!

Comment: Try this: `r = requests.put(url, headers=headers, json=payload)`

Comment: I have added it as an answer, please select it as the correct answer if it solved your issue. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your payload is a `dict` use `json` kwargs in requests lib. `data` works for string payload. Here you go:

```
r = requests.put(url, headers=headers, json=payload)
```