# Python put request. Spotify API put request Malformed Json

Tags: python, api, python-requests, spotify

I would really appreciate some help here. I am trying to use the Spotify API to add albums to a users library. I have been struggling with a Malformed Json Payload, and am completely out of ideas.

Here is a simplified version of what I am currently sitting on

```
url = 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/albums'
payload = {'body': ['01kTgTBiZkCFY3ZH2hBH6u', '4sz6Fn4BYORRLIc1AvQwQx']}
headers = {'Authorization':'Bearer {}'.format(access_token), 'Content-Type':'application/json',}
response = requests.put(url,headers=headers, data=payload)
print(response.json())
```

The error I am receiving is in the json response:

```
{'error': {'status': 400, 'message': 'Malformed json payload'}}
```

I have tried changing requests.put as per below, but all attempts are returning the same error

```
response = requests.put(url,headers=headers, json=payload)
response = requests.put(url,headers=headers, data=json.dumps(payload))
response = requests.put(url,headers=headers, json=json.dumps(payload))
```

Comment: Hey! What type of error are you getting? Also are you using any packages to do this?

Comment: Hey, I am getting a json response: {'error': {'status': 400, 'message': 'Malformed json payload'}}

I am using the requests library

Comment: can you `import json` and then in your response variable set `data = json.dumps(payload)` It seems that one other person is having a similar issue, here is the link: https://github.com/spotify/web-api/issues/502 (might be a different use case but lmk if it helps)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58517684/python-spotify-api-returning-error-400-malformed-json Check this out also!

Comment: Thanks, but this is still returning the same error.

Comment: instead of data, can you do `json = payload`. According to requests documentation, json kwargs takes in a dictionary which is the same type as your payload.

Comment: `response = requests.put(url,headers=headers, json=payload)` something like this

Comment: Still no luck unfortunately :(

Comment: Hey try removing the comma at the end of `headers = {'Authorization':'Bearer {}'.format(access_token), 'Content-Type':'application/json',}`

Comment: Still nothing. Thanks so much for all the help.

Comment: yeah no problem. I'm gonna read more about the Spotify Web API, I'll get back to you.

Comment: Do you know if ur access_token is ur Spotify Client ID or ur Client Secret?

Comment: It is an Oauth token. You can generate a temporary one on this page.
https://developer.spotify.com/console/put-current-user-saved-albums/?ids=01kTgTBiZkCFY3ZH2hBH6u%2C4sz6Fn4BYORRLIc1AvQwQx

Comment: oh sick thanks, im going to try to use ur code. See if i can fix it on my system.

Comment: okay I am also getting the same exact error as you

Comment: do you know how to test whether this is working? I might have been able to get it working i just want to make sure im not sending you a false alarm

Comment: I have managed to use the "Try it" function in the documentation succesfully (Where you create the token)

Comment: I think i got it working, I will post my code as the answer in just a few minutes. I think I know what the issue was.

Comment: I have posted my working code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`07bYtmE3bPsLB6ZbmmFi8d`: This spotify id is for the album, Dancefloor Hits #1. I checked my spotify acct and there it was in my Albums on my acct. Below is my code to run that.

```py
import requests

url = "https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/albums"

payload = {"ids": "27cZdqrQiKt3IT00338dws"}
headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'Authorization': 'Bearer %s' % (access_token) # paste your access token in here
}

''' you can use the same syntax as above but the key was that your ID of album had to be a **parameter** not ***data***. 
To do that you use the params kwarg'''

response = requests.request("PUT", url, headers=headers, params = payload)

print(response.status_code) # should print out 200 when you run the code
# shows whether status was valid
```

Comment: Cool no problem, im glad I could help. just remember to use params. There is actually a spotify library called Spotipy if you want to take a look at that.