# using the put method in Spotify using python

Tags: python, python-requests, spotify

I'm having trouble using the `PUT` method in Python. I'm trying to force a specific device to play a track on Spotify using the `PUT` method as described in their website https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/#endpoint-start-a-users-playback to start/resume the player.

I have managed to acquire a token and used the `GET` method successfully with the requests library, but I'm having trouble writing a PUT command.

This is what I currently am using, but I keep getting a 400 error:

```
url = "https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/player/play"

payload = {"id": "f103fb953eadfb10ed89f8df3fee40be26e354ac"}
headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'Authorization': 'Bearer %s' % (access_token) # paste your access token in here
}
dat= {
  "context_uri": "spotify:album:5ht7ItJgpBH7W6vJ5BqpPr",
  "offset": {
    "position": 5
  },
  "position_ms": 0
}


response = requests.request("PUT", url, headers=headers, params = payload,data=dat)

print(response.status_code) # should print out 200 when you run the code
# shows whether status was valid
```

Comment: Hi, it would be helpful if you shared how you've attempted to do this, so we can see what you might be missing?

Comment: have looked on the internet and used this but keep getting error 400

url = "https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/player/play"

payload = {"id": "f103fb953eadfb10ed89f8df3fee40be26e354ac"} headers = { 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Authorization': 'Bearer %s' % (access_token) # paste your access token in here } dat= { "context_uri": "spotify:album:5ht7ItJgpBH7W6vJ5BqpPr", "offset": { "position": 5 }, "position_ms": 0 }

response = requests.request("PUT", url, headers=headers, params = payload,data=dat)

print(response.status_code) # should print out 200 when you run the code

Comment: According to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61160753/python-put-request-spotify-api-put-request-malformed-json the payload seems to use `ids` and not `id`, and only use `params`. Not sure if `data` automagically serializes JSON.

Comment: tried it and still no joy with code 400

Comment: I suggest try to use `requests.request(...,  json=dat)`. Also Spotify API page says query parameter is called `device_id` but you have payload "id" instead.

Comment: Another suggestion, try "spotipy" python library instead. Same method docs are [here](https://spotipy.readthedocs.io/en/2.19.0/#spotipy.client.Spotify.start_playback).

Comment: hi sorry I tried your suggestion and still no luck I am able to get between error 400 401 and 403 with changing the format of the token but yet no success